# SQL script for multiple reservations by one customer (Restaurant)

Tags: sql, database, duplicates

I need my SQL db to be able to hold more than one reservation for a customer.
However I get some duplicate pk errors.

Here is my SQL script: (I wanna be able to let one customer have more than 1 reserv.)

```
/*
  db_name: Restaurant DB
  update_timestamp: 6.10.2021 @ 09:48
  sign: The Actual Daniel
*/

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS restaurantDB;
CREATE DATABASE restaurantDB;
USE restaurantDB;

CREATE TABLE `bill`  (
  `billID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `payAmount` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`billID`)
);

INSERT INTO `bill` VALUES (1, '$258');
INSERT INTO `bill` VALUES (2, '$420');
INSERT INTO `bill` VALUES (3, '$114');
INSERT INTO `bill` VALUES (4, '$88');
INSERT INTO `bill` VALUES (5, '$137');
INSERT INTO `bill` VALUES (6, '$286');
INSERT INTO `bill` VALUES (7, '$97');
INSERT INTO `bill` VALUES (8, '$110');
INSERT INTO `bill` VALUES (9, '$358');
INSERT INTO `bill` VALUES (10, '$190');

CREATE TABLE `customer`  (
  `customerID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerID`)
);

INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES (1, 'Nero', 'Lee', '420420589');
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES (2, 'Lucius', 'Malt', '578632221');
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES (3, 'Aurelian', 'Keen', '639456773');
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES (4, 'Jasmine', 'Wang', '227453891');
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES (5, 'Sophie', 'Clinck', '905674321');
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES (6, 'Augustus', 'Smith', '523764112');
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES (7, 'Isabelle', 'Niaom', '786554330');
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES (8, 'Alix', 'Black', '009886775');
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES (9, 'Leia', 'Mudworth', '345667228');
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES (10, 'Claudius', 'Reed', '427654221');

CREATE TABLE `meal`  (
  `mealID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sides` varchar(255) NULL,
  `main` varchar(255) NULL,
  `beverage` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mealID`)
);

INSERT INTO `meal` VALUES (1, 'potatos', 'steak', 'wine');
INSERT INTO `meal` VALUES (2, 'ice', 'cube steak', 'spring water');
INSERT INTO `meal` VALUES (3, 'rice', 'cake', 'beer');
INSERT INTO `meal` VALUES (4, 'salad', 'pasta', 'wine');
INSERT INTO `meal` VALUES (5, 'radish', 'noodles', 'soju');
INSERT INTO `meal` VALUES (6, 'rice', 'rice', 'pumpkin juice');
INSERT INTO `meal` VALUES (7, 'butter, honey', 'steak', 'wine');
INSERT INTO `meal` VALUES (8, 'ice', 'salad', 'mineral water');
INSERT INTO `meal` VALUES (9, 'sweet potatos', 'pork', 'beer');
INSERT INTO `meal` VALUES (10, 'sourdough bread', 'fruit bowl', 'mineral water');

CREATE TABLE `order`  (
  `orderID` int NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderID`)
);

INSERT INTO `order` VALUES (1, '21-09-27 13:36:06');
INSERT INTO `order` VALUES (2, '21-02-14 17:18:03');
INSERT INTO `order` VALUES (3, '21-03-27 11:34:16');
INSERT INTO `order` VALUES (4, '21-07-14 15:58:32');
INSERT INTO `order` VALUES (5, '21-02-27 18:16:33');
INSERT INTO `order` VALUES (6, '21-01-14 19:28:12');
INSERT INTO `order` VALUES (7, '21-08-27 16:27:07');
INSERT INTO `order` VALUES (8, '21-06-14 11:21:09');
INSERT INTO `order` VALUES (9, '21-11-27 16:30:03');
INSERT INTO `order` VALUES (10, '21-03-14 17:22:11');

CREATE TABLE `reservation`  (
  `reservationID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `checkIn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `checkOut` datetime NOT NULL,
  `customerForeign` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`reservationID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`customerForeign`) REFERENCES customer(customerID)
);

INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES (1, '21-09-27 13:24:06', '21-09-27 14:17:23', 1);
INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES (2, '21-02-14 17:25:03', '21-02-14 19:22:14', 2);
INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES (3, '21-03-27 11:34:16', '21-03-27 13:34:16', 3);
INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES (4, '21-07-14 15:58:32', '21-07-14 16:58:32', 4);
INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES (5, '21-02-27 18:16:33', '21-02-27 19:16:33', 5);
INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES (6, '21-01-14 19:28:12', '21-01-14 20:28:12', 6);
INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES (7, '21-08-27 16:27:07', '21-08-27 17:27:07', 7);
INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES (8, '21-06-14 11:21:09', '21-06-14 14:21:09', 8);
INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES (9, '21-11-27 16:30:03', '21-11-27 17:30:03', 9);
INSERT INTO `reservation` VALUES (10, '21-03-14 17:22:11', '21-03-14 19:22:11', 10);

CREATE TABLE `table`  (
  `tableID` int NOT NULL,
  `numOfSeats` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tableID`)
);

INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (4, 2);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (5, 4);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (6, 4);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (7, 6);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (8, 6);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (9, 8);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (10, 12);

ALTER TABLE `bill` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_bill_order_1` FOREIGN KEY (`billID`) REFERENCES `order` (`orderID`);
ALTER TABLE `meal` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_meal_order_1` FOREIGN KEY (`mealID`) REFERENCES `order` (`orderID`);
ALTER TABLE `order` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_order_customer_1` FOREIGN KEY (`orderID`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customerID`);
ALTER TABLE `reservation` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_reservation_customer_1` FOREIGN KEY (`reservationID`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customerID`);
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_table_reservation_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tableID`) REFERENCES `reservation` (`reservationID`);
```

This is error I get when trying to insert new reservation for customer with ID of 1
[image: error]